# incomplete dependencies in laravel

Tags: laravel

When i created a project using composer

C:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel tipar  5.4.*

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30)
```

- Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30): Loading from cache
Created project in tipar

> php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 59 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing symfony/css-selector (v3.3.9): Loading from cache
>     - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.0): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.5.0): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.3.9): Loading from cache
>     - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1): Loading from cache
>     - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Loading from cache
>     - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Loading from cache
>     - Installing nikic/php-parser (v3.1.1): Loading from cache
>     - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/debug (v3.3.9): Downloading (100%)
>     - Installing symfony/console (v3.3.9): Downloading (100%)
>     - Installing psy/psysh (v0.8.11): Loading from cache
>     - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/routing (v3.3.9): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/process (v3.3.9): Loading from cache
>     - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.3.9): Downloading (100%)

this is the only output i get, there are some files that are missing.

Comment: I am also having trouble in installing 5.4 error is :[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL  
   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                       
  error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify   
  failed                                                                       
  Failed to enable crypto                                                      
  failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: i tried this but it dint work https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3346#issuecomment-76593763

Comment: Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17. This is the error that i take when i run it on localhost.

Comment: try composer update --no-scripts then composer dumpautoload.

Comment: @Bugfixer this is the output on the terminal after i run the scripts C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar>composer update --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 44 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.3.9): Downloading (100%)

C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar>composer dumpautoload
Generating optimized autoload file.

Comment: @Bugfixer the error has been replaced, this is the updated error after i run the script, 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\public\index.php(36): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipar\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Comment: check if php artisan is working if working run config:cache,config:clear. if not  then u need delete everything inside bootstrap/cache or take backup and then delete.

Comment: @Bugfixer there is only 1 file in my bootstrap/cache at that is .gitignore, when i try to delete and run artisan, the error is still the same.